# How to write mockito junit to catch exceptions

Tags: android, mockito

I am writing tests for Android application in this app i am writing automation,unit tests and for webservices i am using mockito to write tests but for catching exceptions i couldn't find any way to write tests.One way i tried with expected annotation but this is also not catching exception

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
catchException(service).method(parameters);
assertThat(
    caughtException(),
    allOf(
            instanceOf(Exception.class),
            hasMessage("Exception message here"),
            hasNoCause()
    )
);
```

Hope this might guide you in the right direction :)

Comment: i didn't find catchException in mockito